# There is a line in the Javascript cometd chat client distributed in 3.1 that I don't understand

Tags: javascript, cometd

My question is about the _metaConnect function in chat.js. Here's the function:

```
   function _metaConnect(message) {
        if (!$scope.joined) {
            $scope.connected = false;
            _connectionClosed();
        } else {
            var wasConnected = $scope.connected;
            $scope.connected = message.successful === true;
            if (!wasConnected && $scope.connected) {
                _connectionEstablished();
            } else if (wasConnected && !$scope.connected) {
                _connectionBroken();
            }
        }
    }
```

Specifically, what does the line

```
$scope.connected = message.successful === true;
```

accomplish?

Comment: `$scope.connected = message.successful === true;` sets `$scope.connected` to the result of `message.successful === true`

Comment: ... Equivalent to `if (message.successful === true) { $scope.connected = true; } else  { $scope.connected = false; }`

Comment: Or `$scope.connected = (message.successful === true);`. This is because `===` has higher precedence than `=`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Answer (score 1):

`$scope.connected` gets the value of `message.successful === true`.

`message.successful === true` has the value true if `message.successful` has the value `true` or false if `message.successful` has any other value.